# Scope problem with Standalone package in grandchild \input{styles}

Tags: pdftex, miktex, standalone

[MiKTeX on Win7]

I have my document subdivided into various files according to chapters, and I have a series of code snippets in TeX format which I've generated using the `Highlight` package on Ubuntu, that need to be inserted into the chapters.

The problem I'm having is:

- Using the `standalone` package without the `subpreambles` flag,  the symbols defined in `highlight.sty` don't work (Because the `\input` command is in its preamble.)
- Using the `standalone` package with the `subpreambles` flag I get the following error:

  ```
  ! Undefined control sequence.
  <argument> \datapath 
                       /highlight.sty
  l.3 ...ge {alltt}\input {\datapath /highlight.sty}
                                                    \title {wb_ardrone_perform...
  ```
- When I use the `import` package with the `standalone` package commented out,  I get the following error:

  ```
  Figures/wb_ardrone_performance.tex

  ! LaTeX Error: Can be used only in preamble.

  See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
  Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
   ...                                              

  l.2 \documentclass
                    {article}
  ```

Below is a description of my document's structure followed by the code each component has (pruned for relevance).
My document layout is as follows:

High level structure (main) with chapters (children)
The children need to import code snippets (grand-children)
The grand-children need to read highlight.sty.

CODE:
Main (Structure):

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twoside]{article}
\usepackage{standalone}
%\usepackage[subpreambles]{standalone}
%\usepackage{import}
\usepackage{xstring}

\newcommand{\includestandalonewithpath}[2][]{%
  \begingroup%
  \StrCount{#2}{/}[\matches]%
  \ignorespaces 
  \StrBefore[\matches]{#2}{/}[\datapath]%
  \includestandalone[#1]{#2}%
  \endgroup%
}

\begin{document}
  \section{\uppercase{Child 1}}
  \noindent\input{child1}
  %%%   and so on for subsequent chapters  %%%
\end{document}
```

Children (Chapters):

```
% child1
% NO \begin{document} here (Not needed)

\begin{figure}
  \begin{center}
    %%%  THESE are the various commands I've tried.  %%%
    %\input {Figures/wb_ardrone_performance}
    \includestandalone{Figures/wb_ardrone_performance}
    %\includestandalone{C:/Tmp/Figures/wb_ardrone_performance}
    %\includestandalonewithpath {Figures/wb_ardrone_performance}
    %\includestandalonewithpath [mode=tex]{Figures/wb_ardrone_performance}
    %\subimport*{Figures/}{wb_ardrone_performance.tex}
    %\fbox{\includegraphics[width=.40\textwidth]{Figures/wb_ardrone_performance.pdf}}
    %\fbox{\input wb_ardrone_performance.tex}
  \end{center}
  \caption{\label{fig:temp} a simple message in C}
\end{figure}

% NO \end{document} here (Not needed)
```

Grand-child (`wb_ardrone_performance`):

```
\providecommand{\dataPath}{.}
\documentclass[varwidth]{standalone}

\usepackage{color}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{alltt}


%\input{highlight.sty}
\input{\dataPath/highlight.sty}

\begin{document}
  \pagecolor{bgcolor}  <===== doesn't know what bgcolor is!
  \hlstd{}\hlppc{\#ifndef\ \textunderscore WBARDRONEPERFORMANCE\textunderscore }\hspace*{\fill}\\  <===== doesn't know what any of the tokens are!
\end {document}
```

`highlight.sty` (Generated by Ubuntu `Highlight` package):

```
% Style definition file generated by highlight 3.16.1, http://www.andre-simon.de/ 
% Highlighting theme: Kwrite Editor 
\newcommand{\hlstd}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0,0,0}{#1}}
\newcommand{\hlnum}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.69,0.49,0}{#1}}
\newcommand{\hlesc}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{1,0,1}{#1}}
\newcommand{\hlstr}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.75,0.01,0.01}{#1}}
\newcommand{\hlpps}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.51,0.51,0}{#1}}
\newcommand{\hlslc}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.51,0.51,0.51}{\it{#1}}}
\newcommand{\hlcom}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.51,0.51,0.51}{\it{#1}}}
\newcommand{\hlppc}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0,0.51,0}{#1}}
\newcommand{\hlopt}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0,0,0}{#1}}
\newcommand{\hlipl}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0,0.34,0.68}{#1}}
\newcommand{\hllin}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.33,0.33,0.33}{#1}}
\newcommand{\hlkwa}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0,0,0}{\bf{#1}}}
\newcommand{\hlkwb}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0,0.34,0.68}{#1}}
\newcommand{\hlkwc}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0,0,0}{\bf{#1}}}
\newcommand{\hlkwd}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0,0,0.51}{#1}}
\definecolor{bgcolor}{rgb}{1.0,1.0,1.0}
\pagestyle{empty}
```

Hope I've provided all the right info.
I'd appreciate some help figuring out why it's not working.

Cheers,
Nap

*Removed* `\test` from the Grand-Child doc.  Was using it while diagnosing my problem to print.

Comment: It's not possible to run the code as your main is missing (at least) `\documentclass{article}`  you seem to be using color commands but haven't loaded the `color` package anywhere that I can see,

Comment: Why not just `\usepackage{whatever}` in the preamble of your main document? Or just define `\datapath` somewhere it will get read?

Comment: I've added the overlooked statements.  `\datapath` is defined in the `\includestandalonewithpath` command definition in the main file.

Comment: One problem I think I see is that when the `subpreambles` option is set in the main (where the sub-preambles are processed on the next run after they've been gathered into the `.sta` file) , since the `\dataPath` variable isn't set yet (It's set later when the child's `\includestandalonewithpath` command is processed), `highlight.sty` can't be found.
(Is there a way of printing values of variables during the compilation? Like debug print)

Comment: @cfr, when I define a literal value for `\datapath` in my main, it works.  However, I would like to understand how to use the dynamic method to discover the path (make files can do that sort of stuff easy).

Comment: It is confusing that `highlight.sty` has that extension when it is not a package!

Comment: It's generated like that from the highlight package on Ubuntu.
But, from David's answer below, it can clearly be referred to in a `\usepackage` statement.  Thank you both for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `xstring` and `standalone` processing is making this vastly more complicated and fragile than it needs to be, I'd just use `\input`.

In the following I changed `highlight.sty` to make `bgcolor` grey rather than white so it shows up, if you want it white put it back or simply remove the `\colorbox{bgcolor}`

[image]

---

main.tex

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twoside]{article}

\usepackage{varwidth,color,highlight}

\begin{document}
\section{Child 1}

% no!!  \noindent

\input{child1}
  %%%   and so on for subsequent chapters  %%%
\end{document}
```

---

child1.tex

```
\begin{figure}[htp]
  %\begin{center} use \centering not center in figures.
  \centering
    \input{Figures/wb_ardrone_performance}
  \caption{\label{fig:temp} a simple message in C}
\end{figure}
```

---

Figures/wb_ardrone_performance.tex

```
  \colorbox{bgcolor}{\begin{varwidth}{\textwidth}
  \hlstd{}\hlppc{\#ifndef\ \textunderscore WBARDRONEPERFORMANCE\textunderscore }\hspace*{\fill}
  % not defined?\test
\end{varwidth}}
```

---

highlight.sty

```
% Style definition file generated by highlight 3.16.1, http://www.andre-simon.de/ 
% Highlighting theme: Kwrite Editor 
\newcommand{\hlstd}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0,0,0}{#1}}
\newcommand{\hlnum}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.69,0.49,0}{#1}}
\newcommand{\hlesc}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{1,0,1}{#1}}
\newcommand{\hlstr}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.75,0.01,0.01}{#1}}
\newcommand{\hlpps}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.51,0.51,0}{#1}}
\newcommand{\hlslc}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.51,0.51,0.51}{\it{#1}}}
\newcommand{\hlcom}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.51,0.51,0.51}{\it{#1}}}
\newcommand{\hlppc}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0,0.51,0}{#1}}
\newcommand{\hlopt}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0,0,0}{#1}}
\newcommand{\hlipl}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0,0.34,0.68}{#1}}
\newcommand{\hllin}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.33,0.33,0.33}{#1}}
\newcommand{\hlkwa}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0,0,0}{\bf{#1}}}
\newcommand{\hlkwb}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0,0.34,0.68}{#1}}
\newcommand{\hlkwc}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0,0,0}{\bf{#1}}}
\newcommand{\hlkwd}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0,0,0.51}{#1}}
\definecolor{bgcolor}{rgb}{.8,.8,.8}
\pagestyle{empty}
```

---

Comment: I've now realised that I didn't indicate where 'highlight.sty' was located (together with the grand-child docuement).  I've moved it up to where main is to enact your suggestion.  Is it possible to make this happen such that it can remain in its original folder?

Comment: @gone just make sure all folders with needed files  are in your TEXINPUTS path, it shouldn't matter where it is, or where your individual chapter files are, just as you do not worry where `article.cls` is exactly when you do `\documentclass{article}`

Comment: @ David: cheers, done that.  On linux, you can end your path string with `//`  can this be done in windows to recurse?

Comment: @gone yes exactly same path searching library is used.